# " Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null " for Extjs6.0

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

After the page has been running for a while, then the browser prompts for a resize of the browser " Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null "

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Alexander chrome 63.0.3239.132(formal edition)

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs when we are trying to access elements which is not yet initialize or basically NULL. Can you just post you code or let us know which thing you want to achieve??

Comment: First of all, and I find the code for my problem where the two days are under investigation, the development of the system template which can be normal operation, but occasionally this problem occurs (Browse any function module) In changing the browser size when.I'll send out my layout code later。

Comment: Might be, that you have not cleared listeners to an already destroyed component.